# print ([[a,b,c] for a in range(0,x+1) for b in range(0,y+1) for c in range(0,z+1) if a + b + c != n ])

Tags: python, list, printing

```
print ([[a,b,c] for a in range(0,x+1) for b in range(0,y+1) for c in range(0,z+1) if a + b + c != n ])
```

can some one explain me this how this is printing output like mentioned below

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

**Unable to understand the syntax**

Comment: What are your values for `x`, `y`, `z`, and `n`?

Comment: Please write your complete code, including `x`, `y`, `z`, `a`, `b`, `c` and `n`.

Comment: You need more urgent help in learning how to phrase a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x=y=z=1
>>> n=2
>>> print ([[a,b,c] for a in range(0,x+1) for b in range(0,y+1) for c in range(0,z+1) if a + b + c != n ])
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

If x,y,z are all set to 1 and n set to 2, this will only print the lists whose elements don't sum to 2.

Thus, the lists `[0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,0]`, which sum to 2, don't appear in the output.